# How can I enforce code styles for C#/.NET, like IDE0058, IDE0059 and IDE0060?

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, dotnet-cli

I'm looking into enforcing code styles and to start I implemented [IDE0058](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058), [IDE0059](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0059) and [IDE0060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0060) in my .editorconfig, like so:

```
csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable:error
csharp_style_unused_value_assignment_preference = discard_variable:error
dotnet_code_quality_unused_parameters = all:error
```

When I run build in visual studio 2022 on windows I do get errors for them, although the build still succeeds.
However, when I run `dotnet build` from the command line, I don't get any errors and when I searched for the style codes, I couldn't find any mention of them.

My colleague tested it on his macbook, and the mac version of visual studio didn't give any errors. Neither did the command line.

In our gitlab pipeline we also run `dotnet build`, which also passed without any errors.

In all environments we are using .NET 6.0.

Is it possible to enforce these code styles using `.editorconfig`? If so, how?

If not, how can code styles be enforced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following lines to **csproj** file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <AnalysisLevel>6.0-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then in editorconfig additionally to your existing rules add

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0058.severity = error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0059.severity = error
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0060.severity = error
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the project properties:

1. Right-click the project
2. Click "Build"
3. Set `Treat warnings as errors` to `All`:

[image: Treat warnings as errors: All]

However, if you do it, it'll be added only for current configuration which is probably `Debug`.

You can do it manually via UI for both configurations (`Debug` and `Release`).

Or you can edit your `.csproj` file.

This will be added if you set `Treat warnings as errors: All` via UI.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You can duplicate it and change the configuration:

ded if you set `Treat warnings as errors: All` via UI.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'"> // Changed `Debug` to `Release`
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you, this does catch  a lot of warnings, but it still doesn't appear to catch IDE0058, IDE0059 and IDE0060. Do you know if there's a setting for those?